# why can't I access iPad photos library?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm using IImagePickerController to get photos from the photo library.  Works great on the iphone, but won't work on an iPad.  There were solutions suggested to use UIpopoverController.  I was using UIpopoverController in any earlier version, and I couldn't get it to work.  Keep getting an error that the popoverController did not exist.  Below is my code.  Is there a framework that allows you to use UIPopoverController?

```
- (IBAction)getPhoto4:(id)sender {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage ,(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    float actualHeight = image.size.height;
    float actualWidth = image.size.width;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = 320.0/480.0;

    if(imgRatio!=maxRatio){
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
            imgRatio = 480.0 / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = 480.0;
        }
        else{
            imgRatio = 320.0 / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = 320.0;
        }
    }
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Get the data for the image
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);

    // Give a name to the file
    IMAGE_COUNTER = IMAGE_COUNTER + 1;
    NSString* incrementedImgStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"zTempDataFilePleaseDelete%d.jpg", IMAGE_COUNTER];

    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Now we get the full path to the file
    NSString* fullPathToFile2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:incrementedImgStr];

    if(IMAGE_COUNTER == 4) {
        imageView4.image = img;
        photoHeight4 = img.size.height;
        photoWidth4 = img.size.width;
        photoPath4 = fullPathToFile2;
    }

    // and then we write it out
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile2 atomically:NO];

}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}


-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker1
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Can I recommend you learn how to load photos using ALAssetsLibrary ? Your apps can have a custom UI for loading photos which you can write if you were to use ALAssetsLibrary Framework instead of UIImagePickerController. You can make your custom image browser select multiple photos too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:
in .h file implement delegate

```
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

in .m file:

```
@implementation UIImagePickerController(Nonrotating)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
@end
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)


-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
@end

-(void)photoclick
{
    UIImagePickerController *pckrImage=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
            pckrImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            pckrImage.allowsEditing = YES;
            pckrImage.delegate=self;
           // UITableViewCell *cell = [tblIncident cellForRowAtIndexPath:[tblIncident indexPathForSelectedRow]];


         UIPopoverController  * poppickePhoto = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:pckrImage];

            poppickePhoto.delegate = self;
           // poppickePhoto.popoverContentSize =CGSizeMake(320,480);
            [poppickePhoto presentPopoverFromRect:yourbtn.frame inView:yourbtn.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

**update**

```
  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {


        UIImage *choosedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

        yourumageview.image=choosedImage;
        [poppickePhoto dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];



    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.  Probably because I don't understand how to transition back to the imagePickerController/didFinishPicking MediaWithInfo method.  How do I go from poppickePhoto back to relating this to UIImage *image = info[....] in my code?  Or, do I just start using poppickePhoto?  Also, I had a "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:: method just after the code I sent.  Do I still need to orientation code you provided if I already have this?  Your's is substantially more sophisticated.  Again, it work fine with an iPhone.  Maybe not with an iPad?

Answer (score 2):

On iPad you need to display `UIImagePickerController` embedded in `UIPopoverController`.

You can't directly display it using `presentViewController:`

**If you are displaying camera then you can use presentViewController, else you need to use a popover for displaying the image picker in iPad.**

[image: Reference]
Reference:
[UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

---

So instead of:

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Use:

```
UIPopoverController  *photoPop = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[photoPop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(100,100,300,300) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

Check these tutorials:

1. [UIImagePickerController](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPad_Camera_and_UIImagePickerController_Application_%28Xcode_4%29)
2. [UIImagePickerController in iPad](http://technopote.com/how-to-open-uiimagepopovercontroller-in-ipad/)

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.  Probably because I don't understand how to transition back to the imagePickerController/didFinishPicking MediaWithInfo method.  How do I go from photoPop back to relating this to UIImage *image = info[....] in my code?  Or, do I just start using photoPop.  Before I did resize the photo in case it was huge. What does the CGRectMake(100,100,300,300) do to the actual photo?  Do I get an image that is just 200 by 200 pixels?

Comment: @user2353906: No, it is for showing the image picker (popover dimension). What you mean by it didn't work ? Is popover displayed ?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm expecting to see, but nothing happens and the code crashes with no specific error message.

Comment: BTW, this happens before I even send the command to pick and image.

Comment: @user2353906: probably you forgot to add the popover delegate. Anyway check the edited answer. I have added two nice tutorials for you.

Comment: I pulled this section code out of my project just to test it.  That new project incudes the popover delegate, but I get the following error: 2013-06-14 13:51:20.348 testPopover[577:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] called when not running under UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.'  Does that make the issue clearer?  I'll also check out the tutorial.

Comment: @user2353906: You are trying to run on iPhone. UIPopover won't work with iPhone. It is for iPad

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. I ran the tutorial code, and it worked. I want my code to run on both an iphone and ipad.  Is there no way to get photos out of a library in the same code for both iPhone and iPad?

Comment: @user2353906: Unfortunately no. You ne to check the device and do the necesay action

Comment: Wow!  So, check the device and go to separate methods in your code..one for iPhone and one for iPad.  Is there a simple few lines of code for checking whether a device is iPad or iPhone?  Again, thanks for you patience with me.  I'm quite new to coding.

Comment: I used an "if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone/Pad)" like statement. Was able to run my code on both iPhone and iPad.  I wanted to thank you again for helping me.  I'm sure you are busy, and I appreciate the time you devoted to me.